# Parallel execution with data-provider-thread-count and thread-count

Tags: multithreading, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

I have used DataProviders in my tests. I want to execute them in parallel[`@DataProvider(parallel = true)`].

When I give `parallel = methods, data-provider-thread-count = 1 , thread-count =2`.

Total no of thread i want to execute at a given time is 2. **I want the DataProviders to pick up the next input whenever there is an idle thread.** Currently the DataProvider is using the same thread(for one input after another) for execution which is more like sequential.

If I give `data-provider-thread-count = 2 & thread-count =2`, 2X2=4 threads are running in Parallel. This will increase the load when there are 100 DataProvider tests.

Is there a way to control the DP threads from spawning separate thread pool? So we can enable them to be picked up for parallel execution.

Comment: Could you provide us your language which you are using?

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: did you tried like @DataProvider(parallel = true)